# How to tell when xml element is one of multiple or not in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have two powershell scripts:

One using a single `<b>` element:

```
$x = [xml] "<a><b>foo</b></a>"
$x.a.b.length
```

And one using multiple (two in this case) `<b>` elements:

```
$y = [xml] "<a><b>foo</b><b>bar</b></a>"
$y.a.b.length
```

The first script returns the length of the text in the one `<b>` element, the second returns the number of `<b>` elements.

How do I find out if there is one or multiple `<b>` elements.  Clearly the `length` property wont do the job.

I'm using win 8.1 and powershell 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Count` instead:

```
PS> $x.a.b.Count
1
PS> $y.a.b.Count
2
```

Comment: That works - thank you - Count isn't listed when using `$x.a.b | get-member`

Comment: @Graham `| Get-Member` enumerates the items in `$x.a.b`, `Get-Member -InputObject @($x.a.b)` will show you